# Running a java exe out of the SDK

Tags: java, exe, executable, executable-jar

I created a program using Java 8(JDK 8), but when I try to run it on a device that isn't mine (so no JDK), it makes me download a JRE.
1) why don't all programs when you download them make you do this? Is it just most programs aren't using Java? 
2) how to I create an installation exe to install the JRE and the program. (As of now I'm just running my program as an exe).

Comment: @user I think the OP knows this. By the way, you don't need the `JAVA_HOME` for compiling or executing the program. But it may be needed by tools like maven to locate the JDK/JRE installation directory.

Comment: I think this exe is an installer or the program bundled to an exe.

Comment: Idea behind Java is to "write once, run everywhere". But how can it be achieved if all OS work differently? Idea was to create for each OS its specific "translator" who will be using tools available for that OS to produce execution specified in java code (or to be more precise in `.class` files). And that is JRE. Why Java is not preinstalled on each OS? IMO, maybe security (just like browsers don't want to include Flash anymore, but allow users to install it). Anyway since Java 9 and modules system you can use `jlink` to build apps which include specific parts (or whole) JRE for OS you want.

Comment: @user when I said I was running an exe, I bundled a jar into an executable file so I can run it out of the SDK.

Comment: @Pshemo do you have a link I can follow for the jlink?

Comment: I am not sure what kind if information you are looking for. If documentation then take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jlink.html, if examples then googling `jlink example` or `jlink hello world` should give you many of those like https://medium.com/azulsystems/using-jlink-to-build-java-runtimes-for-non-modular-applications-9568c5e70ef4

Comment: Documentation will do perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it just most programs aren't using Java?

Yes, java is a popular programming language but most (desktop) applications are not written in java.

Some programs do also come with a JRE, meaning that it is installed with the program.

> how to I create an installation exe to install the JRE and the program.

The exe could try to download the JRE from the API of e.g. OpenJDK, execute it and wait until it finishes, you could bring an installer with you, you could tell the user to install a JDK or you use an installer template that does one of the things for you.

Comment: How can I find an installer template?

Comment: What build system do you use/want to use?

Comment: Windows and want windows

Comment: I meant build systems like maven, gradle, ant, not the OS.

Comment: What about https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.decyg.innosetup?